# Probability and Combinatorics without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I have a sample space of $A$ and I randomly select $a$ elements, mark them, put them back into the sample space, then randomly select $b$ elements and I want to know what the probability is that $a$ and $b$ have precisely $y$ elements that are the same, how might I go about this?

The way I'm currently thinking about this is to break the problem into two parts:

1. In the first selection I mark $a$ elements. Thus in order for me to choose exactly $y$ elements in the second selection, I must have marked at least $y$ elements in the first selection and now I need to make sure I select exactly $y$ of the marked elements of $a$.

   The event, $E_1$, that I select at least $y$ elements in the first selection I'm confused on. Do I even needs this?
2. The event, $E_2$, that when I select $b$ elements exactly $y$ of these are ones that I selected in the $a$. Can I do this with conditional probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ denote the total number of elements in $A$.

---

Calculate the number of ways to choose $b$ elements from $A$, such that:

- $y$ elements are marked
- $b-y$ elements are not marked

$$\binom{a}{y}\cdot\binom{x-a}{b-y}$$

---

Calculate the number of ways to choose **any** $b$ elements from $A$:

$$\binom{x}{b}$$

---

Hence the probability is:

$$\frac{\binom{a}{y}\cdot\binom{x-a}{b-y}}{\binom{x}{b}}$$

Comment: so the selection of a elements doesn't matter? Like, what if we only select one element the first time (so a = 1) and but y is 10?

Comment: @Auser: Well then it's simply impossible to choose $10$ marked elements because there is only $1$ such element. I've assumed that you are asking the question under the (obvious) restriction of $y \leq a$ and $y \leq b$. For any other case, the probability is obviously $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Regretfully, I do not have enough reputation to comment on your question. :S

If I correctly understand and $A$ is finite, then the following can work.

After marking you have two classes, the marked which has $a$ elements and the non-marked which has $|A|-a$ elements. Denote by $\xi$ the number of elements which are marked from the selected $b$. You are looking for the probability

$$
P(\xi = y),
$$

where $y$ is at most $b$.

$$
P(\xi =y)=\dfrac{\binom{a}{y}\cdot \binom{|A|-a}{b-y}}{\binom{|A|}{b}}.
$$

Here $\xi$ is said to have a hipergeometric distribution. If I misunderstood your problem, please let me know and I can delete the answer to work out other one...